# Connect Java fx application to remotely hosted database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a remotely hosted database. I had been working on an FX application for which I connected to localhost for reading and writing data from database. But now I want to connect my desktop application to the remotely hosted database and read and write data from there. But it shows me the following error.

```
    SEVERE: null
    java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '103.253.39.4' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1037)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.model.DatabaseManager.connect(DatabaseManager.java:38)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.model.FittingDetails.getAllSuppliers(FittingDetails.java:155)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.Layout_AddFittingType.(Layout_AddFittingType.java:52)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.Layout_InsertFittingDetails.(Layout_InsertFittingDetails.java:37)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.MenuItemTask.(MenuItemTask.java:23)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.BasicLayout.(BasicLayout.java:40)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$148(LauncherImpl.java:327)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$43/445051633.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/2028529302.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/2040495657.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1558600329.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:358)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
        ... 5 more
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$148(LauncherImpl.java:327)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$43/445051633.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/2028529302.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/2040495657.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1558600329.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.garciaPlumbing.model.FittingDetails.getAllSuppliers(FittingDetails.java:171)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.Layout_AddFittingType.(Layout_AddFittingType.java:52)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.Layout_InsertFittingDetails.(Layout_InsertFittingDetails.java:37)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.MenuItemTask.(MenuItemTask.java:23)
        at com.garciaPlumbing.view.BasicLayout.(BasicLayout.java:40)
        ... 16 more
```

This what I have done to establish the connection.

```
    public class DatabaseManager {
        private static final String CLASS_FORNAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        private static final String DATABASE_LOCATION = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.2freehosting.com/";//"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "u821323799_grc?";//"GarciaPlumbing2";
        private static final String USERNAME = "u821323799_grc";//"root";

        protected static Connection connection = null;
        protected static PreparedStatement statement = null;

        /**
         * 
         * Connect() method is responsible for establishing any connection to database.
         * 
         */
        public static void connect(){
            try {
                Class.forName(CLASS_FORNAME);
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://mysql.2freehosting.com/u821323799_grc?"
                        + "user=u821323799_grc&password=celloviii1");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DatabaseManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }        
        }
    }
```

Please someone help me out with a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the problem is not at the code, and in the host server, which you need to allow remote connections, specifically the host you're trying from

Comment: Is it wise to post the username and password in plain text on the Internet?  I hope those aren't the real credentials.  Read up on how to GRANT permissions to a given username, password, and host.

Answer (score 0):

> java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host
>   '103.253.39.4' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

It means that the MySQL Server at the remote system is not configured to accept remote connection from `103.253.39.4` with the provided credentials. Please configure the remote MySQL Server to accept remote connection and try again.

You may try: [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)